# Is there any way to deploy a model for image classification in Flutter after tflite model issues?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, pytorch, flutter-dependencies, tflite

can we do real time real time image classification or object detection in a flutter app?

i am making an app where i have to classify items on the real time in my flutter app. After the issues with tflite model is there any way i can deploy a model for image classification in flutter?

Comment: Have you had a go, what issues do you have? Do you have any code that you can show.